# JdbcTemplate queryForList return value in case of no results

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

The question is pretty much summed up in the title. What will JdbcTemplate.queryForList() return when the query returns no results. Will it return an empty List or null value? I couldn't find a definitive answer from the documentation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The javadoc states that it will return

```
a List of objects that match the specified element type
```

If there's no element, the list is empty.

Comment: I was not sure if I could make that assumption. Seems I could. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4):

It will return an empty list. So you can test it with `list.isEmpty()`. It will return true in this case.